# jsView - How to render the content of a custom tag with its props as its data?

Tags: jsviews

I have custom tag which can have itself as an inner tag and I want to bind it its `props` as  `data`. I can change the first `test` tag `title` property and see the change but cannot do that for the inner `test` tag. I think it is because of the wrong arguments of `this.tagCtx.content.render()`. Below is the example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jsrender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.observable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.views.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div>{^{>title}}{^{:content}}</div>
</script>

<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {^{test title='Test1'}}
        {^{test title='Test2'}}
        {{/test}}
    {{/test}}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.views.tags({
        test: {
            render: function(){
                this.tagCtx.props.content = this.tagCtx.content.render();
                return this.template.render(this.tagCtx.props, this.tagCtx, this.tagCtx.view);
            },

            template: "#testTemplate"
        }
    });

    $.templates({myTemplate: "#myTemplate"});

    $(function () {
        $.link.myTemplate('#container', {});

        $('#editTitle').click(function () {
            $.observable($.view('#container div:first div').data).setProperty('title', prompt());
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="editTitle">EditTitle</span>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the inner tag is being rendered as a string, not as a data-linked tag, since the `this.tagCtx.content.render()` call is simply calling the render method on the compiled template corresponding to the block content.

If you want to render as a data-linked tag, you need to call `this.tagCtx.render()`.

In addition, in calling `this.tagCtx.render()` you need the tag to render its content, and not another template. Setting `template: "#testTemplate"` will cause the tag to use that template instead of the content. So what you need is something along these lines:

```
var template = $.templates("#testTemplate"); 

$.views.tags({
    test: {
    render: function() {
            var tagCtx = this.tagCtx;
            tagCtx.props.content = tagCtx.render();
            return template.render(tagCtx.props, undefined, tagCtx.view);
        }
    }
});
```

You probably don't want to pass in tagCtx as context in the `template.render(...)` call. You can pass in tagCtx.ctx, or simply undefined...

Comment: Now `#parent.data` works but `~root` does not. I asked it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238589/jsview-in-contrast-to-parent-data-root-does-not-work)