# jsView - In contrast to #parent.data, ~root does not work in this case

Tags: jsviews

Below is the example where `#parent.data` works and the first title can be changed. But when `#parent.data` is replaced with `~root`, `test2` tag is not rendered.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jsrender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.observable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.views.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script id="test1Template" type="text/x-jsrender">
        <div>{^{>title}}{{:content}}</div>
        {{test2}}
        <h1>{^{>#parent.data.title}}</h1>
        {{/test2}}
    </script>

    <script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
        {^{test1 title='Test Title 1'}}
        {^{test1 title='Test Title 2'}}
        {{/test1}}
        {{/test1}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.views.tags({
            test1: function () {
                this.tagCtx.props.content = this.tagCtx.render();
                return $.templates.test1.render(this.tagCtx.props, undefined, this.tagCtx.view);
            },

            test2: function () {
                return this.tagCtx.render();
            }
        });

        $.templates({myTemplate: "#myTemplate",
            test1: "#test1Template"
        });

        $(function () {
            $.link.myTemplate('#container', {});

            $('#editTitle').click(function () {
                $.observable($.view('#container > div:first').data).setProperty('title', prompt());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="editTitle">EditTitle</span>

<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~root` is a reference to the data object or array you passed in initially - the top-level data. It is not the immediate parent data. In your case ~root will be the `{}` you passed in with the `link.myTemplate()` call.

*Update added later:* (Response to question in comment below about ~root)

From JsViews point of view, when any block tag content is rendered, it is also a 'view' - where a template is rendered against data. The views make up a hierarchy, and the top-level one is the one for which the data is exposed as ~root. So if you want to provide special short cut aliases for data at intermediate levels, you can do so, but that is for you to do. Declaratively that is done as in [this example](http://borismoore.github.io/jsrender/demos/step-by-step/11_accessing-parent-data.html). In your case you are calling the intermediate level template render programmatically, so you can do the equivalent by providing a reference as a context variable:

```
return $.templates.test1.render(
    this.tagCtx.props, 
    {mydata: this.tagCtx.props}, 
    this.tagCtx.view);
```

Now you can write

```
<script id="test1Template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div>{^{>title}}{{:content}}</div>
    {{test2}}
    <h1>{^{>~mydata.title}}</h1>
    {{/test2}}
</script>
```

Comment: I thought `~root` is root to the template. Is there any plan to specify a variable which is the root data that the template is rendered with. To be clear, I want to access the data that the template is rendered with. Here it is `this.tagCtx.props`. I want it to be proportional to each template and I want to avoid `parent` referencing in which I made mistakes. For example between choosing `#parent.parent.data` or `#parent.parent.parent.data`. I use This kind of root data many times in my templates. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again. Besides your solution I tried wrapping my templates in `{{include ~mydata=#data}}` tag and it works. But your solution is cleaner.